# Xamarin save photo with latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin. I want to take a photo and write to console the latitude and longitude, where the photo was taken. I'm trying to get it with the following code:

```
var exif = new ExifInterface(picUri.Path);
var latLong = new float[2];
float? lat = null, lng = null;
if (exif.GetLatLong(latLong))
{
    lat = latLong[0];
    lng = latLong[1];
}

if(lat != null && lng != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Latitue {0}, Longitude {1} ", lat, lng);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Some value is equals to null");
}
```

And I've got `Some value is equals to null` in the console. What am i missing?

Comment: You can search the Xamarin.Forms.Maps plugin. I use my last application. When the device open GPS, about 2 secound after, find the device location.
  

https://i.hizliresim.com/YOrdkl.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in the manifest